# Bind Crystal Report Multiple Times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I want to bind a **single crystal report multiple times**. Scenario is that i have a gridview  with **some number of customer details** and a print button with each row of gridview. when i click on print button **yearly statement of that customer shown in crystal report**. it works fine. But Now i want an print all button which is outside the gridview and when i click on this button **single crystal report will be bind for all the customer is which  in the gridview**.

Is this Possible to do that? Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: have to use group by in your crystal report??

Comment: Yes you can do it. You have to make sure that both the queries which are fetching the data should be same. In codebehind whcih binds the data to gridview and in crystal report command. Then only you will get expected results.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set this up?

is the report getting a customer id and the fetching the data from the db? (pull)
if so change the customer id parameter to an array/list and change your report query from where id = parameter to something like where id in (parameter)

if you use a push mechanism (get all the data beforehand and send it to the report) 
you can send a list of customers instead of a single customer to the report

vague questions give vague answers :/